# Speakers are coming up as mic input?

Tags: sound, microphone, headphones

For some reason on my computer, whenever i plug in my speaker into the audio jack nothing comes up, but when i plug it into the mic jack it pops up. On windows you can select the input device once you plug it in(whether its a microphone or speaker/headset). On ubuntu i don't get this option, it just assumes the input is a microphone (probably because its a mic jack). So i have no sound, but im sure if i can somehow make ubuntu think that its a speaker plugged in it would work. Any way to change it? I think of the jack as one of those audio/mic slots that work for either or. It's just reading my speaker as a mic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the [alsa-tools-gui](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=alsa-tools-gui) package which bundles an application called **hda-jack-retask** that permits "retasking" of hardware audio ports.

To install the package run the following in a terminal window ( <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  +  <kbd>ALT</kbd>  +  <kbd>t</kbd> ):

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-tools-gui
```

Afterwards, you should be able to start `hdajackretask` and reconfigure the ports as needed.

Comment: YOU'RE A LIFE SAVER THANK YOU SO MUCH THIS WORKED LIKE A CHARM <3